# iOS Get JSON response from AFNetworking HTTP POST method with JSON parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, json, post, afnetworking-2

I am getting a `404` error while posting with JSON parameters at the `https://api.hackerearth.com/codemonk/v1/topic­detail/`. The server uses POST HTTP method to get a `topic`'s details & JSON response is expected when successful. The POST parameter is `id` of the `topic` object. POST Parameters are expected to be in JSON.
I am using AFNetworking as follows -

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@1 forKey:@"id"];

NSString *str = @"https://api.hackerearth.com/codemonk/v1/topic­-detail/";

NSString *encodedStr = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[manager POST:encodedStr
   parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"responseObject : %@",responseObject);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    NSLog(@"error : %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

This is regular stuff but don't know why I can't seem to get it correct now. I am only getting a `404 Page Not Found` error. This is not a server side issue for sure. Any help guys ?

Comment: You set id value 1 which means that link;

https://api.hackerearth.com/codemonk/v1/topic-detail/id=1

And this links giving 404. Am i missed something?

Comment: It is a POST request, I need to pass  {"id":1} as json parameter body to this post request.

Comment: Sending POST request with json dict you provided as a body also gives 404 error. Could you provide documentation please? maybe API expect some headers

Comment: are you sure you are using correct link? it seems like a server side issue. i tried to run your request with postman and it also give the same result.

Comment: The documentaion is pretty much standard one, here's the link to it : http://bit.ly/1jb9fLb

Comment: The sole GET request mentioned in the doc (@ bit.ly/1jb9fLb) is working but I can't get any of the POST requests to work.

Comment: Please check your URL (copy it and paste in command-line). Hyphen symbol is wrong in your URL and XCode displays it wrong! Please see how this the same URL is displayed in XCode and Terminal
http://joxi.ru/Y82QNJnT37kGAd.jpg

Comment: See my answer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

operationManagerInstance.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
```

=============UPDATE

I have 404 when copying your URL. It's because hyphen symbol between topic-detail is not actually hyphen. It's some special character that doesn't work.

https://api.hackerearth.com/codemonk/v1/topic­-detail/

Instead I deleted it and typed hyphen manually and it works fine.

Comment: had tried this explicit json setting, again tried it, but still getting a `404` error

Comment: for the sweet love of God, YES
this was it, the hyphen was the culprit - that was the reason why none of the POST requests were not working (all of them had hyphens)
Thanks a ton mate :)

Comment: Your question made my day! it was much more interesting than just to send JSON in POST request body:)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line

```
NSString *encodedStr = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Try the following:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@1 forKey:@"id"];

NSString *str = @"https://api.hackerearth.com/codemonk/v1/topic­-detail/";

[manager POST:str
   parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"responseObject : %@",responseObject);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    NSLog(@"error : %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```